# How To Use Facebook Real Time API To Get The Number Of Likes On My Page?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to get real time updates of how many page like we have. I have been trying to use Facebooks real time API with no luck. I have looked for tutorials but the don't seem to be up to date. Does any one have any idea of how to get a real time count of Facebook likes from a page?

Thanks
Fran

Answer (score 0):

You can´t use the Realtime API for that. The Realtime API is for new feed posts on the Page, for example. You can get the likes easily with a basic API call: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page

You will only get the current likes, of course. So you would need to refresh it every few seconds.

Comment: I got this from FB graph reference does this not mean you can get the likes?
 
"likes: 
The number of users who like the Page. For Global Brand Pages this is the count for all pages across the brand."

Comment: yes? that´s exactly what i was pointing out in my answer. the link i posted shows that "likes" is a field of the page endpoint.